# efficient string end replace

Tags: php, replace

I would like to see if the there is a way to do this without `preg_replace`, just string functions.

I am using this

```
$str = "-41d3vUYHtK3D-GI3QXiVhvfR-zNooU7U_--2697";
preg_replace("/\-\d+$/i","",$str)
```

to remove everything that follows and including the last "dash"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not a requirement that the last characters have to be digits, then you can use [`substr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strrpos` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strrpos.php):

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '-'));
```

Or in PHP 5.3.0, [`strstr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
$str = strstr($str, '-', true);
```

If, on the other hand, you want to remove the last dash and characters *only* if the following characters are digits, then using regular expressions would be the easier way.

Comment: Returns `-41d3vUYHtK3D-GI3QXiVhvfR-zNooU7U_-`, substract 1 from the strrpos to get the dash as well.

Comment: @Robus: There are two consecutive dashes in the original string. The code is exactly doing what the regular expressions does, it only removes the last one.

Comment: i accept the firs of your answers that works fine, thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "-41d3vUYHtK3D-GI3QXiVhvfR-zNooU7U_--2697";

for($i=strlen($str)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
    if($str[$i] == '-'){
        $result = substr($str,0,$i);
        break;
    }

}
echo $result;
```

Returns `-41d3vUYHtK3D-GI3QXiVhvfR-zNooU7U_-`